# View and template rendering changed in Grails 3

Tags: grails, gsp

I've just discovered a change in Grails 3 about view and template rendering :

In Grails 2.x, i could render a page as view enven if there is no body tag in the page. Say i have a test.gsp containing :

```
<h1>this a test</h1>
```

In grails 2.x, i can render it by using

```
render(view:'test')
```

but in grails 3, **nothing is rendered**,

**Except**

1. add body tag surround h1
2. render as template

Is this a change in Grails 3 as i thought ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In grails 3 you need to specify your view page with directory as like

> render(view: "/Your_Class/test")